# cross client and server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

SendMessage.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList  runat="server" ID="listMessagereceiver"></asp:DropDownList>
<textarea id="txtBodyMessage" name="txtBodyMessage">    </textarea>
<asp:Button OnClick="btnSendMessage_Click" runat="server" ID="btnSendMessage"  />
```

Script

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtBodyMessage',{language : 'fa',on :{}} );
```

Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listMessagereceiver.DataSource=list;
  listMessagereceiver.DataBind();
}
protected void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //how can access to `txtBodyMessage`
}
```

`txtBodyMessage` is client side how can access this?

This is a good way for send message?

Is there a better way؟

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the value that was posted, nothing else, then `request.form["txtBodyMessage"]` will work.

Alternatively, `<textarea id="txtBodyMessage" name="txtBodyMessage" runat="server">    </textarea>` would give you more control as a server htmlcontrol. This works as a half-way house.

Finally there's make it a full web control as pj suggested above but use clientid to find out what it called in the page, not id. ID is the server side control name.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your script is on a ASPX page you could change the text area to:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtBodyMessage" name="txtBodyMessage" MultiLine="True" runat="server">    </asp:TextBox>
```

and your javascript to:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( '<%=txtBodyMessage.ClientID %>',{language : 'fa',on :{}} );
```

and then in your event handler:

```
protected void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //access `txtBodyMessage` with this.txtBodyMessage
}
```

Comment: Error: uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.editor.replace] The element with id or name "<%=txtBodyMessage.ID %>" was not found.

Comment: is that line: CKEDITOR.replace( '<%=txtBodyMessage.ID %>',{language : 'fa',on :{}} ); on an aspx page ? like i said above, <%=txtBodyMessage.ID %> will only render the ID of the textbox on an aspx page, not if you have it on a normal .js file

Comment: that's strange, the inline tag <%= (...) %> should output the value of txtBodyMessage.ID properly.. can you post the whole block of javascript you're trying to run?

meanwile a possible workaround would be:
 - add an attribute CssClass="jquery_ckeditor" to your asp:TextBox
 - in your jquery code do $('.jquery_ckeditor').ckeditor( function() { /* callback code */ }, {language : 'fa',on :{}} ); instead of the CKEDITOR.replace

Comment: Error: $(".jquery_ckeditor").ckeditor is not a function
Source File: http://localhost/BackSite/js-css/lib/ControlPanelPP.js
Line: 823

Comment: please check if you are properly including the necessary ckeditor scripts, as long as jquery, like stated in the ckeditor for jquery docs: http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery

Comment: you need to use ClientID, not Id